# Use CodeDOM or Mono - .NET

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net

I understand I can use either the [CodeDOM](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/y2k85ax6.aspx) or [Mono](http://www.mono-project.com/CSharp_Compiler) for compiling and executing C# code on the fly. Which of these are suggested given the security concerns of executing code and flexibility?

EDIT: I need to create an editor in which any user can enter code and choose to execute it. My concern is that if they have malicious code (accessing the file system for example) then I need to take precautions to prevent this from happening. How would I do this using CodeDOM or Mono?

Comment: Recommended by whom? Seems like this runs the risk of becoming a "Product XYZ is the best!" question.

Comment: Can you revise this to be a bit more specific (e.g cite your concerns specifically)? It appears that you are indeed asking for a specific objective answer, but the wording of your question is rather broad.

Comment: @Tim - I updated my post with more details.

Answer (score 1):

For maximum flexibility, Mono C# compiler should be the choice.

I don't think both provide any security protection inside, as that should be something you do in your own code.

Comment: So potentially it can run any type of code (Ex: accessing the file system)? What would be the simplest way for adding security protection?

Comment: It is very hard to prevent certain code from executing (maybe filtering out certain namespace/class usage), but you can always limit who can ask your application to execute certain code (authentication), and do audit (log that user account, and log what is the code being executed somewhere).

Comment: With `CodeDom` you can limit the references in terms of external assemblies. You can't stop them from using namespaces inside of the assemblies you do link against however.

Comment: @sixlettervariables - I am not sure if I can use the exclude assembly approach. I may exclude the System.IO assembly to prevent the access to the file system, but there could be potential risks in other assemblies or what about things like infinite loops?

Comment: @Dusty: The problem is, there is no `System.IO` assembly, rather it is a namespace inside of mscorlib. You can create a new `AppDomain` with limited permissions, pass the code needing to be compiled, and have a library of yours execute it.

Answer (score 1):

You could use `CodeDom` anyways, compile and run the code in another `AppDomain`. My suggestion would be to insert the code as a `CodeSnippetStatement` into a `CodeMemberMethod`, that way they can't *break out* or are constrained by what you provide.